# Magento 2 add custom data to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, template, knockoutjs

I am trying to add some additonal data under checkout items summary (right sidebar).
I am not figuring out how to get dynamic data from maybe Block (or other way).

Here it is what I have already done:

**1 / Add my component to checkout_index_index layout**
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="foo-bar-summary" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Foo_Bar/js/sample/summary</item>
                                                            <!--<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">summary</item>-->
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Foo_Bar/sample/summary</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2 / Create component**
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/web/js/sample/summary.js`

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'ko'
    ], function ($, Component, ko) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

**3 / Add template**
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/web/template/sample/summary.html`

```
<div class="component-wrapper">
    <div data-bind="text: 'Test sample'"></div>
</div>
```

---

**4 / Same thing with M2 Block / Template logic**
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/templates/summary.phtml`

```
<div id="sample-summary" data-bind="scope: 'sample-summary'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#sample-summary": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "sample-summary": {
                        "component": "Foo_Bar/js/sample/summary",
                        "template" : "Foo_Bar/sample/summary"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

---

With that I can see my `Test sample` above the items list.

- Do I really need to use `Kojs` or can I just use the "basic" way to
  implement Block / template / layout ?
- How can I call my block / template in the `checkout_index_index` layout ?
- Are there others ways to call dynamic data into Kojs ?
- Why my Component is inserted before while it is in `itemsAfter` node ?

Comment: How about the other way around? How to pass input values from frontend to backend? I dont want to save the custom values in order,i want to export them elsewhere

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK I figured out how to pass data to Kojs templates.
I had to create a class `SampleConfigProvider` implementing `ConfigProviderInterface` returning an array with my data

File `Foo/Bar/Model/SampleConfigProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SampleConfigProvider
 */
class SampleConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'foo' => [
                'bar' => 'data',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Then in my `frontend/di.xml` add a new `CompositeConfigProvider`
File `Foo/Bar/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="foo_bar_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Foo\Bar\Model\SampleConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

In my component call my configurations
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/web/js/sample/summary.js`

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'uiComponent',
        'ko'
    ], function ($, Component, ko) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
            },
            getSampleTotal: function () {;
                return window.checkoutConfig.foo.bar;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

In my `Kojs` template
File `Foo/Bar/view/frontend/web/template/sample/summary.html`

```
<div class="component-wrapper">
    <p data-bind="html: getSampleTotal()"></p>
</div>
```

**NOTE:**

For people wondering

> Why my Component is inserted before while it is in itemsAfter node?

It is a Magento known issue. I opened an issue on GitHub for that: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8344