# Magento 2 Payment method : Add custom Select field that I can use in checkout process

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, payment-gateway, custom-field

I am working on a Payment Gateway integration in Magento 2. The payment method is working fine and its listed on checkout page.
I need to add a Custom Select Field on the Checkout process.

[image]

> MODULE/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="offline-payments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">OmniCapital_Finance/js/view/payment/omni_finance</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="omni_finance" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/omni_finance.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'omni_finance',
                component: 'OmniCapital_Finance/js/view/payment/method-renderer/omni_finance-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }    
);
```

> MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/omni_finance-method.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'OmniCapital_Finance/payment/omni_finance'
            },
            getMailingAddress: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
        });
    }
);
```

> di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="OmniFinanceFacade" type="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="code" xsi:type="const">OmniCapital\Finance\Model\Payment\OmniFinance::METHOD_CODE</argument>
            <argument name="formBlockType" xsi:type="string">OmniCapital\Finance\Block\Form</argument>
            <argument name="infoBlockType" xsi:type="string">OmniCapital\Finance\Block\Info</argument>
            <argument name="valueHandlerPool" xsi:type="object">OmniCapitalValueHandlerPool</argument>
            <!-- argument name="validatorPool" xsi:type="object">OmniCapitalValidatorPool</argument -->
            <!-- argument name="commandPool" xsi:type="object">OmniCapitalCommandPool</argument -->
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="omni_finance" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="omni_finance" xsi:type="object">OmniCapital\Finance\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <!-- Configuration reader -->
    <virtualType name="OmniFinanceConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="omni_finance" xsi:type="const">OmniCapital\Finance\Model\CustomConfigProvider::METHOD_CODE</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

   </config>
```

And here is Config Provider Class.

```
namespace OmniCapital\Finance\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface {

    const METHOD_CODE   = 'omni_finance';
    protected $method = [];
    protected $escaper;

    public function __construct(
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        Escaper $escaper
    ) {
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->method  = $paymentHelper->getMethodInstance('omni_finance');
    }

    public function getConfig() { 
        $config = [
            'payment' => [
                'omni_finance' => [
                    'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $config;
    }

    public function getStoredCards(){
        $result = array();
        $result['0'] = "Test";
        $result['1'] = "Test1";
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please follow this [blog](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157073/magento-2-add-custom-data-to-checkout) so you can get idea how to pass data payment form. create configprovider.php and di.xml.

I have posted basic code which you can modified as per your requirement. create SampleConfigProvider.php under File

> Namespace/Modulename/Model/SampleConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

   namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

   use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

   /**
     * Class SampleConfigProvider
    */
   class SampleConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
   {

    public function getStoredCards(){
      $result = array();
      $result['0'] = "Test";
      $result['1'] = "Test1";
      return $result;
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {

    $config = array_merge_recursive($config, [
        'payment' => [
            \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment::CODE => [
                'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    return $config;
   }
}
```

Then in my frontend/di.xml add a new CompositeConfigProvider

> File Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_payment" xsi:type="const">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment::CODE</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="test_payment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\SampleConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

> add below method in omni_finance-method.js add method :

```
        getStoreCard: function() {
            return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.storedCards;
        },

        getCardList: function() {
            return _.map(this.getStoreCard(), function(value, key) {
                return {
                    'value': key,
                    'type': value
                }
            });
        },
```

add in omni_finance.html file :

> Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\template\payment

```
<select name="payment[subscription_id]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
                                data-bind="
                                    attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                                    options: getCardList(),
                                    optionsValue: 'value',
                                    optionsText: 'type',
                                    optionsCaption: $t('--Please Select--'),
                                    ">
                    </select>
```

you can add what ever you like it will display under relevant payment method section. Please follow this [blog](https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-magento2/) for basic understanding.

> Don't forgot add constant CODE in your payment.php

Comment: if its working don't forgot accept answer so it will useful to other also.

Comment: `getStoreCard: function() {
    return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.omni_finance.storedCards;
},`.  Tried this but it throws following error.

Comment: `TypeError: window.checkoutConfig.payment.omni_finance is undefined`

Comment: you need to post your code

Comment: Updated the Question. Please check

Comment: you forgot to add method in MODULE/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/omni_finance-method.js file. Please check my answer. you find code under add below under this label method in omni_finance-method.js add method :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67757/discussion-between-yogesh-and-jitendra-rana).

Comment: Hi, Yogesh can you please assist me with Config Reader. Everything else is working fine now.

Comment: Are you referring about SampleConfigProvider ?

Comment: Yes. Can you please come in chat ?

Comment: quite busy in work . share your question or create new question and share me link , i will reply there

Comment: [check this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199388/magento-2-payment-config-provider-not-working/199395?noredirect=1)

Comment: check and replied you as get time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67938/discussion-between-jitendra-rana-and-yogesh).