# Magento 2 Payment : Config Provider not working

Tags: magento2, configuration, payment-methods

I have followed [sample-module-payment-gateway](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) to implement Payment method in Magento 2.

But for some strange reason, Custom Config Provider in Magento is not working. It throws Following error :

> TypeError: window.checkoutConfig.payment.test_finance is undefined
>
> Here is the di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Test_finance" xsi:type="object">TestCapital\Finance\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    
    <virtualType name="TestFinanceFacade" type="Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Adapter">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="code" xsi:type="const">TestCapital\Finance\Model\Payment\TestFinance::METHOD_CODE</argument>
            <argument name="formBlockType" xsi:type="string">TestCapital\Finance\Block\Form</argument>
            <argument name="infoBlockType" xsi:type="string">TestCapital\Finance\Block\Info</argument>
            <argument name="valueHandlerPool" xsi:type="object">TestCapitalValueHandlerPool</argument>
            <!-- argument name="validatorPool" xsi:type="object">TestCapitalValidatorPool</argument -->
            <!-- argument name="commandPool" xsi:type="object">TestCapitalCommandPool</argument -->
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    
    <virtualType name="TestFinanceConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="test_finance" xsi:type="const">TestCapital\Finance\Model\CustomConfigProvider::METHOD_CODE</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    
    <!-- Value handlers infrastructure -->
    <virtualType name="TestFinaceGatewayValueHandlerPool" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ValueHandlerPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">TestFinaceConfigValueHandler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="TestFinaceConfigValueHandler" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\ConfigValueHandler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configInterface" xsi:type="object">TestFinanceConfig</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="TestCapital\Finance\Block\Info">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="config" xsi:type="object">TestFinanceConfig</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

> TestCapital/Finance/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php

```
namespace TestCapital\Finance\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface {
    
    const METHOD_CODE   = 'test_finance';
    
    public function getConfig() {
        $config = [
            'payment' => array (
                self::METHOD_CODE => array (
                    'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
                )
            )
        ];
        return $config;
    }
    
    public function getStoredCards(){
        $result = array();
        $result['0'] = "Test";
        $result['1'] = "Test1";
        return $result;
    }
    
}
```

> TestCapital/Finance/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/test-finance-method.js

```
getStoreCard: function() {
    return window.checkoutConfig.payment.test_finance.storedCards;
},
```

> TestCapital/Finance/view/frontend/web/template/payment/omni_finance.html

```
<label>Select Finance Package</label>
<select name="payment[subscription_id]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
            data-bind="
                attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                options: getCardList(),
                optionsValue: 'value',
                optionsText: 'type',
                optionsCaption: $t('--Please Select A Package--'),
                ">
</select>
```

Comment: Try with js,     return window.checkoutConfig.payment.test_finance.storedCards;

Comment: use testFinance instead of test_finance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eventually got this Resolved.

I had misplaced `di.xml`
once i moved di.xml to `etc/frontend` folder everything works fine now.

Anyone looking for this, Here is the correct location for di.xml

> Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom_payment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\CustomConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

> Namespace/Modulename/Model/CustomConfigProvider.php

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\SamplePaymentGateway\Gateway\Http\Client\ClientMock;

class CustomConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface {
    public function getConfig() {
        $config = array();
        return $config;
    }       
}
```

Comment: This is a total stupid thing, I do not understand why Magento can not use it from the etc directory. I sucked an hour with this while I found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your js file as below,

```
window.checkoutConfig.payment.testFinance.storedCards
```

Set your js file code,

```
getStoreCard: function() {
    return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.testFinance.storedCards
},
```

Run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade,
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Why what is wrong with an underscore? Is it naming convention?

Comment: Yes you have to keep naming convention with code.

Comment: So do I need to change that in COnfigPrivder class as well?

    `'payment' => array (
                'test_finance' => array (
                    'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
                )
            )`

Comment: Its better to change at those points also.

Comment: Its not the case. The config Provider class is not being called. There is some misconfiguration in `di.xml`

Comment: When i try to add `test_finance` in existing Payment method's config provider it works just fine.

Comment: Also when i Dump and Die in other working Payment method's ConfigProvider class script execution halts. But its not the case with my Extension. When i Dump and Die in my ConfiogProvider class script execution does not stop.