# magento 2 payment method does not show up in checkout page frontend

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I'm trying to implement a new payment method with Magento 2 , so i have implemented the below code to display the payment method as an option within payment methods list , however the issue is "onemethod.js" is not loading from "method.js" despite method.js loading successfully without issues , thank you in advance for the assistance .

> test/test1/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method.js:

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
],
function (
    Component,
    rendererList
) {
    'use strict';

    var config = window.checkoutConfig.payment,
    testType = 'test';
    if(config[testType].isActive)
    {  
    rendererList.push(
        {
            type: testType,
            component: 'test_test1/js/view/payment/method-renderer/onemethod'
        }
    );
    }

    /** Add view logic here if needed */
    return Component.extend({});
}
);
```

> test/test1/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/onemethod.js:

```
define(
[

'jquery',
'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/iframe',
'mage/translate'
],
function ($, Component, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'test_test1/payment/method',
            timeoutMessage: $t('Sorry, but something went wrong. Please contact the seller.')
        },

        getCode: function() {
            return 'test';
        },

        isActive: function() {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.isActive;
        },

        getScript: function(){
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.urlForm;
        },

        getAction: function(){
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.redirect;
        },

        getPaymentMethod:function()
        {
            return window.checkoutConfig.payment.paymentmethod;
        }
    });
}
);
```

> test/test1/view/frontend/web/template/payment/payment/method.html:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" data-bind="attr: {src: getScript()}">
        </script>
        <form class="paymentWidgets" data-bind="attr: {action: getAction(),data-brands: getPaymentMethod()}">
            <!-- ko template: --><!-- /ko -->
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

> test\test1\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace test\test1\Model\Ui;


use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use test\test1\Gateway\Config\Config;
use test\test1\Model\Adapter\testAdapter;
class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const CODE = 'test';
    private $config;
    private $adapter;
    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        testAdapter $adapter
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'isActive' => $this->config->isActive(),
                    'redirect' => $this->config->getRedirectUrl(),
                    'paymentmethod' => $this->config->getPaymentMethod(),
                    'urlForm' => $this->adapter->makeReqCAP()
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

> test/test1/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider"> <arguments> <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array"> <item name="test" xsi:type="const">test\test1\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</i‌​tem> </argument> </arguments> </type>    
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider"> <arguments> <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array"> <item name="test_test1_config_provider" xsi:type="object">test\test1\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider</item> </argument> </arguments> </type> </config>
```

test/test1/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="test" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">test_test1/js/view/payment/method</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="test" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete guidance for custom payment display on front end. Please take this as [reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198587/magento-2-payment-method-add-custom-select-field-that-i-can-use-in-checkout-pr/198642#198642) . You have missed di.xml.

Comment: my di.xml in frontend           <type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="test" xsi:type="const">test\test1\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</item>
         </argument>
     </arguments>
 </type>

Comment: <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test_test1_config_provider" xsi:type="object">test\test1\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>

Comment: it's seem that there is no error. right?

Comment: and this my configprovider                                                                                 const CODE = 'test';
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'isActive' => $this->config->isActive(),
                    'redirect' => $this->config->getRedirectUrl(),
                    'paymentmethod' => $this->config->getPaymentMethod(),
                    'urlForm' => $this->adapter->makeReqCAP()
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

Comment: Please update question with this code.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work

Comment: you should post your error also,

Comment: There is no error to post but the payment method does not show up!!!

Comment: Check in network tab your js & phtml called or not.

Comment: only method.js called

Comment: Okay . that's issue. just add payment.php under model & defined your payment method code. I am not sure for this solution.

Comment: It's didn't work also

Comment: No idea brother. but i am sure you just make small mistake so both file js & html not getting. once its get your payment method display on front end.