# Magento 2 : Saved Credit cards in a dropdown in custom payment

Tags: magento2

I have an online payment module where a user will be redirected to merchant page and by entering credit card details, the order will be created.I am saving those credit card details in db.

And I need to show those saved cards as a dropdown on a checkout page.

So For that I have created a new custom offline payment module where I need  to show those details in dropdown and on selecting particular credit card, those details need to attach to payment object and order being placed

Can you please guide on how to achieve it in magento2 as the payment code is rendering from HTML pages

Comment: Storing credit card data in your db is not safe & valid ,

Comment: @Yogesh : As of now,i am storing those details in db later i will be fetching it from payment gateway

Comment: Okay , Please post your code so getting more idea about that.

Comment: @venki Can u please check my [Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225832/magento2-custom-payment-module-with-drop-down-list-is-not-working) I tried to follow the Answer for this Question, I couldn't make it. if possible please share your module.

Comment: @venki Have you able to achive your requirment? Actually I also want that. I have saved card details in db but now I want to use that card details for order place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please follow this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198587/magento-2-payment-method-add-custom-select-field-that-i-can-use-in-checkout-pr/198642#198642) so you can get idea how to pass data payment form , this is basic version you need to add your data so you can get card drop down there same way. create configprovider.php and di.xml.

I have posted basic code which you can modified as per your requirement. create SampleConfigProvider.php under File

> Namespace/Modulename/Model/SampleConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

 namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

 use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

 /**
  * Class SampleConfigProvider
 */
 class SampleConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
 {

  public function getStoredCards(){
    $result = array();
    $result['0'] = "Test";
    $result['1'] = "Test1";
    return $result;
  }

  public function getConfig()
  {

  $config = array_merge_recursive($config, [
     'payment' => [
        \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment::CODE => [
            'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
        ],
    ],
  ]);
  return $config;
 }
}
```

> add below method in test-method.js add method :

```
getStoreCard: function() {
        return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.storedCards;
    },

    getCardList: function() {
        return _.map(this.getStoreCard(), function(value, key) {
            return {
                'value': key,
                'type': value
            }
        });
    },
```

> add in your_html.html file (Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\template\payment) :

```
<select name="payment[subscription_id]" class="select input-text required-entry" 
                            data-bind="
                                attr: {id: getCode()+'_payment_profile_id'},
                                options: getCardList(),
                                optionsValue: 'value',
                                optionsText: 'type',
                                optionsCaption: $t('--Please Select--'),
                                ">
                </select>
```

Comment: I followed the above steps and successfully created select field with credit card details dropdown in the checkout page.Can i know how i can attach those details to payment object while placing order

Comment: ok sure i will create another question

Comment: Don't forgot to accept it :)

Comment: Tried to accept it but it showing "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: You are not able to upvote , you can accept answer because after 15 reputation you are able to give upvote.

Comment: Done acceped the answer

Comment: Thank you i will also reply your second question as i get time for it.

Comment: ok Please find the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201028/magento-2-how-to-get-select-field-data-selected-to-be-posted-in-checkout-page

Comment: How to set stored credit card as selected by default in checkout magento 2 ?