# Magento 2 : how to get Select field data selected to be posted in checkout page while placing order

Tags: magento2

[Magento 2 : Saved Credit cards in a dropdown in custom payment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201002/magento-2-saved-credit-cards-in-a-dropdown-in-custom-payment/201008#201008)

From the above link, i have successfully created select field with credit card details dropdown in the checkout page.Can i know how i can attach (or post that data) those details to payment object while placing order in magento2.

I have added the code in my payment model

```
   public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
       {
          parent::assignData($data);
          $post = $data->getData()['additional_data'];
          $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalData($post);
          return $this;
       }
```

Is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its correct method , There is 2 table **quote_payment , sales_order_payment** both are stored value.

**quote_payment** store value for quote of your cart , **sales_order_payment** store your order payment related information. but storing information after placing order field name is same as table field name. you are setting all information in additional_information.

> add below method in test-method.js add method :

```
 getData: function() {
   return {
    'method': this.item.method,
    'additional_data': {
      'test_field':jQuery('#'+this.getCode()+'test_field').val(),
                }
            };
        }
```

> in your_html.html file
>   (Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\web\template\payment) :

if your payment method code is test_payment then your field id is same with like test_payment_test_field.

> you get this data in payment.php file (Namespace/Modulename/Model/Payment.php)

```
 public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
 {
    parent::assignData($data);
    $post = $data->getData()['additional_data'];
 }
```

Here $post is your posted form value array from checkout page.

Comment: I will give a try and update you

Comment: Okay on Monday.

Comment: We are getting the $post = $data->getData()['additional_data']; but we are not using or assigning to it.

Comment: Post your payment.php code

Comment: I have edited my question.please check

Comment: I figured out and used the following code:
public function assignData(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $data)
{
  parent::assignData($data);
  $postId = $data->getData()['additional_data'];
  $creditCardInfo=serialize($rowsArray);
  $this->getInfoInstance()->setAdditionalInformation($creditCardInfo);
  return $this;
}

Comment: thanks for guiding me in right direction.I will accept the answer once i test extensively

Comment: let me know if you have any question.

Comment: @venki : Can you share your module? actually I have also the same requirment.