# Magento 2 - pass string from AbstractMethod::isAvailable to method-renderer (display it at checkout)

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, checkout-page

I have custom method in my store (I used `\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod` class). In the `isAvailable` method, I get a string that I would like to display to the customer at the checkout. Now, the checkout looks like this:

[image]

But I would like to be able to display additional message here, like this:

[image]

The additional string is constructed in isAvailable, so all I need is to pass it to method-renderer.js or checkout_index_index.xml (I think).

I can also construct the string in custom controller, so I was thinking of adding some JS to checkout that will hit custom controller with HTTP GET request and then add it to the source, but I hope there is a better way to do it.

Comment: you need to add additional string on checkout page right ?

Comment: @Yogesh yes, I need to display string when choosing payment option. But this string is different every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted basic code for passing data to checkout payment form which you can modified as per your requirement. create SampleConfigProvider.php under File path :-

> Namespace/Modulename/Model/SampleConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

 namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

 use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

 /**
   * Class SampleConfigProvider
  */

 class SampleConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
 {

   public function getStoredCards(){
      $result = "This is your string";
      return $result;
   }

   public function getConfig()
   {

     $config = array_merge_recursive($config, [
       'payment' => [
          \Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment::CODE => [
            'storedCards' => $this->getStoredCards(),
         ],
       ],
    ]);
   return $config;
 }
}
```

Then add CompositeConfigProvider in frontend/di.xml

> File Namespace/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Payment\Model\CcGenericConfigProvider">
   <arguments>
    <argument name="methodCodes" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="test_payment" xsi:type="const">Namespace\Modulename\Model\Payment::CODE</item>
    </argument>
   </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="test_payment_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Modulename\Model\SampleConfigProvider</item>
    </argument>
 </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

> add code in your js file which are present in give path
>   (Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer)
>   :

```
   getStoreCard: function() {
        return  window.checkoutConfig.payment.PAYMENTMETHODCODE.storedCards;
    },
```

> Now you can get this string your html file which is located on
>   (Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/template/payment)

```
<span><!-- ko i18n: getStoreCard() --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

You can adjust location of code based on where you want to display,You can take a reference this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198587/magento-2-payment-method-add-custom-select-field-that-i-can-use-in-checkout-pr/198642#198642) & this [blog](https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-payment-method-magento2/) .

You should not add string in `isAvailable` method because when you check in parent class its return boolean value